# How can I display a FolderBrowserDialog in LINQPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I want to browse for a folder in a LINQPad script so I tried using FolderBrowserDialog. It didn't work.

Here is a snippet showing what I'm doing?

```
string path = "";
var browser = new FolderBrowserDialog { ShowNewFolderButton = false };
if (browser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    path = browser.SelectedPath;
}
```

This runs and hangs on the line with ShowDialog() with the yellow execution pointer against that line, but the folder browser dialog isn't visible.

I know that there is an overload for ShowDialog() that takes an `IWin32Window owner` argument and thought that might be the solution, but haven't yet figured out how to get an IWin32Window for the main LINQPad window. I hoped the Util class might provide a way but unless I'm missing it, it doesn't seem to.

Anyone have advice on getting around this problem?

Comment: Not happening here. Your code works without problems

Comment: Darn. I was afraid of that. I sometimes connect my iPad as a second screen. I better check that there isn't a phantom screen that the dialog is opening on.

Comment: Display settings only shows one monitor while the iPad isn't connected so that's not it. Tried Alt-Space to open the system menu on the dialog window but it opens for the LINQPad itself.

Comment: What version of LinqPAD? Free or paid?

Comment: Paid. Premium Edition v5.02.03(AnyCPU)

Comment: Rebooted my computer on the off chance that would affect this but it didn't. The result is the same after rebooting.

Comment: The same for me..... well that's a mistery. References? Using? Permissions? something that could get in the way of the standard System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: Idea: try declaring with the full namespace _System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog xxx = new ...._

Comment: I'm going to create a small EXE in Visual Studio to test this and see what happens.

Comment: Fully qualified namespaces made no difference either.

Comment: Coding up a test in VS has shed some light on the problem. Firstly static analysis suggested that FolderBrowserDialog should be disposed so I wrapped it in a using. Did the same in the LINQPad script but that made no difference. But when I hit F5 in VS to run my code it threw ThreadStateException in ShowDialog(), saying "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process." Adding the attribute solved it.

Comment: Strangely when I ran either the debug or release binaries before adding the attribute, they both just hung, presumably in the same way LINQPad is hanging. After adding the attribute the code ran in VS and both debug and release binaries worked as expected. None of that helps in LINQPad. I have no idea how to add the attribute for a C# Statement(s) script so changed to C# Program and added the attribute to Main() but it still hangs up on ShowDialog().

Comment: Reproduced. go to the LinqPad preferences and set Run Queries in MTA Threads to false.

Comment: Thanks but that's not it. Mine was already set to false.

Comment: Weird, setting it to true results in your observed behavior, setting it to false works again..

Comment: I'll toggle it. Might unstick something. :-)

Comment: Fixed it. It's running each query in its own process that caused it. Turned that off and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `Run each query in its own process` option to true is the cause of the problem. Setting that option back to the default false allows the code described above to run as expected.

However, making this change disables the built-in debugging. Furthermore the behaviour is still slightly problematic.

On first running the script the dialog is displayed and the script runs to completion after Ok or Cancel is selected. However, on running the script a second time it hangs as described in the question. After cancelling the execution and running it again the dialog displays but on the time after that it hangs again, and so on.

It was pointed out that setting the `Always use fresh application domains` option may resolve this and it does, allowing the dialog to display on every execution of the script.

Comment: Try to enable "Always use fresh appdomain" in the settings and see if that helps.

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks.

Comment: I've found that setting to be problematic in many cases and should really be a per-program setting and not a global setting.

Answer (score 3):

Not solution, but an alternative, the `FilePicker` controle (part of new LinqPad Input Controls).

you can write:

```
new FilePicker().Dump().TextInput += (x, e) => ((FilePicker)x).Text.Dump();
```

or:

```
var picker = new FilePicker();
picker.TextInput += (x, e) => {
    var fileName = picker.Text;
    //action with the file...
};
```

full example:

```
void Main()
{
    new FilePicker().Dump().TextInput += (x, e) => procces(((FilePicker)x).Text);
}

void procces(string file)
{
    file.Dump("chosen file...");
    //...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem with LINQPad 5.  I needed a folder picker similar to the file picker.  Your solution worked without me having to modify LINQPad5 settings.  The problem was the dialog was staying in the background. So here's how I got your snippet to work with that dialog in focus.  Instead of using the FolderBrowseDialog.ShowDialog() I used the overload that passes in a windows form.  I created a new form with description and window position then passed that to ShowDialog.  That allowed me to set the description and window positioning.

```
string path = "";
using ( var browser = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog { ShowNewFolderButton = false })
{
    browser.Description = "Select Folder For Foo Processing";
    var form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form(){TopMost = true, TopLevel = true};
    var result = browser.ShowDialog(form); 
    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        path = browser.SelectedPath;            
    }       
}   
path.Dump();
```

I tried to initialize the form in ShowDialog with the settings, but had problems so I opted to declare it before show dialog.  Hope this helps anyone with this problem.